# Html.HiddenFor with preset value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This part was sloved thanks to `Ethan Brown`
I want to set the value of my `Html.HiddenFor` helper with preset value 
This is my code :

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.idv, new { @value = ViewBag.id })%>
<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.etat, new { @value = "false" })%>
```

But when execute my code i get the error that model.idv and modele.etat are null. 

 
This is seconde part no sloved till now :

This is my action :

```
public ActionResult Reserver(string id)

    {
        var model = new Models.rservation
        {
            idv = id,
            etat = false
        };
        return View(model);
    }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Reserver(Models.rservation model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                entity.AddTorservation(model);
                entity.SaveChanges();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {

                return View(model);
            }
        }
```

And this is my view page :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Reserver", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form" })) { %>
//some code textbox to fill
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
<% } %>
```

So when i click on submit button the model.idv is set again on null value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way to set a preset value is to pass it in via the model (MVC appears to ignore the "value" parameter if you set it).  To accomplish what you're looking for, in your action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {
  var model = new MyModel {
    idv = myPresetId,
    etat = false
  };
  return View( model );
}
```

Then you don't have to do anything in your view except have:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor( model => model.idv ) %>
<%: Html.HiddenFor( model => model.etat ) %>
```

Comment: it works, but the problem In my view page i got some information that user need to complete and send button when i clic on send the the idv is set it again at value null can u explain me how to slove this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that `idv` is null when you process it in the `HttpPost` action?

Comment: Could you update your question with your `HttpPost` action, then?

Comment: Everything looks good now; I don't know why you're still getting null.  Can you confirm that you're setting `idv` to something that's not null in the `Reserver(string)` action?  If you just try to invoke that action without a parameter, `idv` will be null, and then there should be no surprises.

Comment: In other words, set a breakpoint on the line `return View( viewModel )`, and see if `viewModel.idv` is the value you expect.  If it is, look at the source for your rendered HTML page.  You should see the hidden input with the correct `value` parameter.  If that's correct, there's something wrong with your view...that might be the next thing you'll want to include in your question.

Comment: I have done Some break point and test, so when i call my action `reserver` the `idv` get the value `string id` till now all works fine. but when i checked `model.idv` i discovered that it's null what means thas `idv` was not sended with succes in my view.

Comment: It's not clear from your quesetion: are your `Html.HiddenFor` calls *inside* your `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: Oh!  You need to put `Html.HiddenFor( model.idv )` *inside* your `Html.BeginForm`...otherwise, the model will not be updated with that value when you pass it back to the `HttpPost` controller.